# How can I get request information when run as cgi in apache?

Tags: c, http, cgi

Never used cgi before, always being a PHP guy,in which I can simply get the request information as easy as `$_REQUEST`.

How can I supposed to get it in c?

Answer (score 0):

The CGI standard

http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/linux/cgi/ch03_01.htm

One of many CGI libraries in C

http://cgi-c.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I'm seeking of a hello world example to get request info in c,so no libraries should involve...

Comment: @compile-fan: The data is sent over standard in, as the book describes.  Most anyone using CGIs (perl, php, C, shell) always use libraries instead of parsing the CGI protocol data directly, but whatever makes you happy.